# Angular strict mode breaking CustomValidator on email form field

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm defining an email form field:

```
this.form.addControl('email', new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required, CustomFormValidators.isValidEmail
]));
```

And using a CustomFormValidators class with a isValidEmail method

```
static isValidEmail(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {

    if (!control) return; // <- ERROR HERE

        const regex = new RegExp(..email regex..);
        if (regex.test(control.value)) return null;

        return { isValidEmail: true };
    }
```

And, with Angular new strict mode rules I'm getting this error:

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors | null'.
```

I could not figure it out how to solve this error.

Comment: Return *something* other that nothing (undefined) on the line causing the error. Like, null, or a ValidationErrors object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the signature indicates, the return value has to be `ValidationErrors` or `null`.

The `return` instruction implicitly returns `undefined` instead of `null` which explains the error you observe.

Write this instead:

```
if (!control) return null;
```

Or just remove this line as the condition may never evaluate to `true` (a control instance is always being passed as a parameter of a validator)

Comment: I won't return null, cause (I'm not sure enough) a Null return indicates that the Validation passed without errors.

Comment: did you consider simply removing this line?

Comment: I did, and that's why I selected your answer as a right one :)